# xpath to select immediate XML child by element name

Tags: .net, xml, xpath

In a WPF application I use the following function:

```
using System.Xml;

static class XmlHelper {
    public static XmlElement ImmediateChild(XmlElement owner, string name)
    {
      foreach (var sub in owner)
        if (sub is XmlElement e && e.Name == name)
          return e;
      return null;
    }
}
```

I have never been able to find an xpath to obtain the same result, like this:

owner.SelectSingleNode(someXPath)

Please note that I don't want to pick a node if it only matches the name without being a direct descendant

Comment: Why do you need XPath or that helper if you work with `XmlElement`? It has an indexer property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.item?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_XmlNode_Item_System_String_ so you can do `owner[name]` to access the first child element by name.

Comment: And if you think you need XPath why does `owner.SelectSingleNode(name)` not work?

Comment: Thanks Martin, I never realized the indexer was there